# Why can't maven parse the expression in the parent's version?

Tags: java, maven

I came across a problem with a maven project build.
My project structure is as follows

```
 my-message
 |
  ---my-message-api
 |
  --- my-message-provider
```

Below is the pom.xml code

```
my-message.pom

<parent>
<groupId>com.xiaofeng.my</groupId>
<artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>my-message</artifactId>    
<version>${my-message.version}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<properties>
    <my-message.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</my-message.version>
</properties>
<modules>
    <module>my-message-api</module>
    <module>my-message-provider</module>
</modules>

my-message-api.pom
<parent>
<groupId>com.msh.my</groupId>
<artifactId>my-message</artifactId>
<version>${my-message.version}</version>
<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

my-message-provider.pom
<parent>
    <groupId>com.msh.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-message</artifactId>
    <version>${my-message.version}</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>my-message-provider</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.msh.my</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-message-api</artifactId>
        <version>${my-message.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

maven install output

```
Failed to execute goal on project my-message-provider: Could not resolve dependencies for project 
com.msh.my:my-message-provider:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.msh.my:my-message-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.msh.my:my-message-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.msh.my:my-message:pom:${my-message.version}
in nexus (http://nexus_url:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)
```

Why can't maven parse the expression in the parent's version? please help me

Comment: You can use a property if you do it correctly. See the docs https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't use a variable in the specification of a parent in a module.  Maven needs to be able to resolve the whole model structure before it can resolve variables.

Comment: See https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.4/maven-model-builder/ about the order of all steps. parent resolution is done before model interpolation (i.e. expression resolution)